# How to convert String value (pin) to use in digitalWrite(pin,boolean) method in Arduino with Nodemcu

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I want to convert my String variable to a value that I can use as a pin number in

```cpp
digitalwrite(pindata, boolean);
```

Please note that this is a NodeMCU board and its pin names are like D0, D1 etc. Not like Arduino numbers. My String might contain values like `"D3"`, `"D4"`, `"D5"` etc.

Code:

```cpp
void post() {
  String data = server.arg("msg");
  Serial.println(data);
  pinPulse(data,1000); // <<-- what here wola it's a String
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Got this data " + data);
}

void pinPulse(char pin, int pulsetime) {
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin, 1);
  delay(pulsetime);
  digitalWrite(pin, 0);
}
```

Comment: That function accepts a `char` not a `String`. And why is the pin number a `char` and not an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping from pin name to pin number is defined in [pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.4.1/variants/nodemcu/pins_arduino.h).
Since the names are sequential, you can define the pin numbers in an array and them access them with an index.
e.g. D5 with the index 5 which has the value 14.

To convert `"D5"` into `5`, you need first to get rid of the `'D'` with `.substring(1)` and then convert the rest (`"5"`) into an integer with `.toInt()`.

```cpp
static const uint8_t NAME2PIN[] = {D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10};
//                                 16   5   4   0   2  14  12  13  15   3   1

void post() {
    String data = server.arg("msg");
    Serial.println(data);
    if (data.length() >= 2 && data[0] == 'D') { //check if it's a valid pin name
        uint8_t pin = NAME2PIN[data.substring(1).toInt()]; //skip the first character (D) and convert it to an integer
        pinPulse(pin, 1000);
        server.send(200, "text/plain", "Got this data " + data);
    }
}

void pinPulse(uint8_t pin, int pulsetime) {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin, 1);
    delay(pulsetime);
    digitalWrite(pin, 0);
}
```